# Does not upgrade the progress bar when coming back in UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uiprogressbar

I am performing a download through Download Manage class and updating a progress bar view according to the received bytes in the delegate connection didReceiveData.

Everything is working fine when I am on the page where downloading is happening but when I am going to some other view controller and coming back to my downloading page, the connection delegate functions are being called while transition of page but coming back does not upgrade the progress bar.

Thats my code

```
for (NSInteger row = 0; row < [downloadManager.downloads count]; row++)
{
    if (download == downloadManager.downloads[row])
    {
        currentTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

        [self updateProgressViewForIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0] download:download];

lbl_percentage.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f%%",((double) download.progressContentLength / (double) download.expectedContentLength)*100];

        lbl_received_data.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ / %@",[self transformedValue:(double) download.progressContentLength],[self transformedValue:(double) download.expectedContentLength]];

        double downloadSpeed = (double) download.progressContentLength / (currentTime - startTime);

        lbl_speed.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/sec", [self transformedValue:downloadSpeed]];

        NSLog(@"Download Running");

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can yuor post your code?

Comment: i am get perfect value of percentage , download speed but doesn't display in UILabel

Comment: does your code called inside a block?

Comment: do you see the correct value using NSLog?

Comment: when i click download button it works fine but when go back and again comes in UIViewController Download Still Running because i shaw that Download Manager Receive Data method continuous Calling

Comment: are you sure the label is connected to the correct IBOutlet? Can you update the text for example and just to test in the ViewDidLoad?

Comment: yes My label correctly connected to the IBOutlet..if is not connected so why first time i am getting perfect output

Comment: did you try to use the dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //Update here your label
        });

Comment: yes i was trying   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ }); and [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{}); both doesn't work

Comment: How is declared the UILabel in the .h file?

Comment: Does the lbl_received_data label work correctly?

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl_received_data;

Comment: just show my App' screen shot everything will be perfect. but when i go back and again come in this view label won't display value

Comment: What happen if after update your label you add another label to show a counter or something that changes during the transfer? Can you try?

Comment: for getting data ,  speed and percentage i am taking only 3 labels

Comment: can I suggest this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803189/setprogress-is-no-longer-updating-uiprogressview-since-ios-5

Comment: Even if is not a good solution, you can put the information about progress in a string and use a local notification to update the content of the labels. It's sounds so bad?

Comment: Another suggestion probably here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235365/ios-uiprogressview-only-updating-once

Comment: no its not work for me :(

Comment: not only progress bar i am not getting value for received data ,  download speed and download percentage

Comment: can you show (updating your question) where your for cycle is exactly? In which function?

Comment: At this point try with a local notification and in this case you can manage in a separate place the updates

Comment: just look what i did

Comment: did you set some delegate to update the progress bar?

Comment: i am using YLProgressbar and i set only <DownloadManagerDelegate>

Comment: Can you show how you set the delegate? My idea is that when you change from a viewcontroller to another you loose the reference to the delegate.

Comment: I don't know YLPProgress bar.. Do you have some code to init the Download Manager? Can you show it?

Comment: Try to use [[self downloadManager] setDelegate:self]; also in viewDidAppear method.

Comment: I played all my cards... I'm sorry :-(

Comment: If you are sure the code is executed... at this point try with a local notification ... no other ideas

Comment: but does download manager derive from a uitable?

Comment: No i my complete code i am not using tableview

Comment: where I find the mail id?

Comment: I send you an email.

Comment: mail sent. I wait for your code and I hope to see in it this evening or tomorrow If I find something I write you! Bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[self downloadManager] setDelegate:self];
}

-(IBAction)btn_Download_click:(id)sender
{
    if ([self downloadManager]) {
        [[self downloadManager] setDelegate:self];
    }else{
        self.downloadManager = [[DownloadManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
        self.downloadManager.maxConcurrentDownloads = 1;
    }

    downloadData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

    NSLog(@"coverimg%@",coverimg);

    NSString *string=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.virtueinfotech.com/moralstory/pdf/%@",coverimg] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSURL *reqURL = [NSURL URLWithString:string];

    startTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

    [self Readfunction];
    [self.downloadManager addDownloadWithFilename:filePath URL:reqURL];

}
-(IBAction)btn_Read_click:(id)sender
{
    [self Readfunction];

    PdfReadView *pdfRv = [[PdfReadView alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:pdfRv animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - Download Manager Delegate Methods

- (void)updateProgressViewForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath download:(Download *)download
{
    if (download.expectedContentLength >= 0)
    {
        // Calculate the progress.
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [self setProgress:(double) download.progressContentLength / (double) download.expectedContentLength animated:YES];

            lbl_percentage.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f%%",((double) download.progressContentLength / (double) download.expectedContentLength)*100];

            lbl_received_data.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ / %@",[self transformedValue:(double) download.progressContentLength],[self transformedValue:(double) download.expectedContentLength]];

            double downloadSpeed = (double) download.progressContentLength / (currentTime - startTime);

            lbl_speed.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/sec", [self transformedValue:downloadSpeed]];
        });
    }
    else
    {
        [self setProgress:(double) (download.progressContentLength % 1000000L) / 1000000.0 animated:YES];
    }
}
- (void)downloadManager:(DownloadManager *)downloadManager downloadDidFail:(Download *)download;
{
    [self setProgress:0.0f animated:YES];
    UIAlertView *alt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops !!" message:@"Downloading Failed...." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alt show];
}

- (void)downloadManager:(DownloadManager *)downloadManager downloadDidReceiveData:(Download *)download;
{

    lbl_total_size.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self transformedValue:(double) download.expectedContentLength]];

    for (NSInteger row = 0; row < [downloadManager.downloads count]; row++)
    {
        if (download == downloadManager.downloads[row])
        {
            currentTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [self updateProgressViewForIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0] download:download];
            });
            NSLog(@"Download Running");

            break;
        }
    }
}
```